# How to implement a call system equal to whatsapp in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, call, whatsapp, onesignal

does anyone know how to implement a call system in React native similar to whatsapp? That is, even with the application open in the background or simply the phone blocked, an interface is opened through a notification to decide whether to accept or reject the call, I am currently handling the notifications with OneSignal